# Can we illustrate pdf of Normal distribution with mean and variance following Normal by analytic expression?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I just wonder if pdf of Normal distribution with mean and variance which are normally distributed can be expressed in analytic formula, i.e.

$
\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)
$ where $ \mu $ ~ $ \mathcal{N}(m, d^2)$ and $\sigma$ ~ $Gamma(k, \theta)$

Let's say that I pick a random variable as time goes(t=1,2,.....,n). When I pick a random variable from $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ as time goes, each time the distribution is changed rather than fixed.

So, can $
\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)
$ where $ \mu $ ~ $ \mathcal{N}(m, d^2)$ and $\sigma$ ~ $Gamma(k, \theta)$
 be expressed as analytic expression?

Comment: Indeed $\sigma^2$ can't be a Normal, since $\sigma^2>0$ and support of any normal is $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Sorry. I was confused. I modified the error. Thank you.

Comment: Seems to me similar to a Bayesian problem obtaining normal posterior from normal prior and normal data.